# Dynamics CRM Field Service. Colors of rows of schedule board

Tags: dynamics-crm

[image: Schedule Board]

1. The rows of schedule board are white by default. I would like to apply colors alternation to them to make them look like these Excel rows on the picture. How could I do it?

[image: Colors alternation in Excel]

2. How to add color change *on hover*? It works out of the box for cells of resources and the work order rows (see the picture), but not for the whole rows on the calendar area.

Comment: Probably a new idea need to be submitted

Comment: Chrome users can use Stylus extension and you can provide css table for them. https://add0n.com/stylus.html

Comment: You can submit an idea & share the url here: https://experience.dynamics.com/ideas/categories/list/?category=a2fa5aca-3f2d-e811-813c-e0071b6ad011&forum=bee3d862-df65-e811-a95d-000d3a1be7ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last time when I checked with MS PG team on this topic - they expressed that it is aligned with Design principles of UCI. So no alternate row colors available in grid or calendar.

You can create an idea and based on community votes, MS may give that option in future. For now instead of manipulating DOM/CSS in any unsupported way, stay away from it. :)